# If one item is displayed as a block, rotate another item by 180 degrees JS

Tags: javascript, html, rotation

I have a menu and an arrow that opens the menu when it's clicked. I want the arrow to turn upside down (rotate by 180 degrees) when the menu is being shown, and to turn back when it's closed. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<button class="mobile-menu-btn mobile-menu-btn-films" onclick="toggleMenuFilms()">
  <div id="btn-films"></div>
</button>
<div id="mobile-menu-sub-div-films">
  <ul>
    <li>
      Item 1
    </li>
    <li>
      Item 2
    </li>
    <li>
      Item 3
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function toggleMenuFilms() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mobile-menu-sub-div-films");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

I want to add something that says "if (x.style-display === "block") { rotate.btn-films } else { do nothing }" but I don't know how. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add a classname to your element and use a transition for rotation values

Answer (score 0):

In this example I change the class name of the parent element. By controlling the class name I can change the appearance of both the button and the menu.

```js
function toggleMenuFilms(event) {
  var menu = event.target.closest('div.menu');
  menu.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
div#mobile-menu-sub-div-films {
  display: none;
}

div#btn-films::before {
  content: 'arrow';
}

div.menu.open #btn-films {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

div.menu.open #mobile-menu-sub-div-films {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <button class="mobile-menu-btn mobile-menu-btn-films" onclick="toggleMenuFilms(event)">
  <div id="btn-films"></div>
</button>
  <div id="mobile-menu-sub-div-films">
    <ul>
      <li>
        Item 1
      </li>
      <li>
        Item 2
      </li>
      <li>
        Item 3
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```